# Where does LogMeIn Control Panel store the control panel settings?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, windows-registry, logmein

I am trying to script some aspects of installing **LogMeIn Control Panel** on industrial workstations running Windows 10 that may or may not have internet access once commissioned. Namely, I am trying to uncheck **Lock when connection has been lost** and **Lock when connection has been timed out**. settings.

LogMeIn Control Panel shows up as **LogMeInToolKit.exe**, which functions as the host to which an outside client attaches for remote access.

I am trying to find the place where LogMeIn Control Panel saves settings, so I can script the installation, minimizing technician time and the number of dissimilar installations. The options I want to change are not adjustable during installation.

I have tried using **Process Monitor**, but I don't see LogMeInToolKit.exe writing registry keys that correspond to changes I'm making in the program. I also don't see any settings file in the installation folder that appears to store these settings.

Am I missing some secret settings stash?

EDIT:
Found these settings at:

```
HKLM:\SOFTWARE\LogMeIn\V5\RemoteControl\LockConsole
HKLM:\SOFTWARE\LogMeIn\V5\RemoteControl\LockConsoleTimeout
```

Comment: Double-check there isn't a setting changing in `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\LogMeIn\ ` or `HKCU:\Software\LogMeIn\Client\ `. The actual exe may be different since the control panel is just the UI for the service. Procmon will let you filter by registry path instead of name, but it can be kind of jank

Comment: @Cpt.Whale - Found it! HKLM:\Software\LogMeIn\V5\RemoteControl .... Wasn't on my radar at all til I went through key by key. Thanks!